# Very low quality flag declined, and still question was closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

My very low quality flag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688110/how-to-create-scrolling-calender) (10k only now) was declined with the following reason

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

However, the question was later closed as off-topic which makes me wonder what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Low Quality != Off Topic.

Comment: @Martijn I'm pretty sure this particular question is both...

Comment: @CodyGray The question itself is salvageable through edits. Not that it'd help a lot since it'd still be off topic, but there's no reason to outright delete it.

Comment: @CodyGray: It can still be edited to fix the grammar, at which point it is **still** off-topic.

Comment: Yes, you can edit anything. But even once you're done, that question will still be "low quality" (*and* off topic). I suppose my standards are too high.

Comment: @CodyGray It won't be "low quality" in the sense of "severe formatting or content problems" which the flag requires. Otherwise I'd agree with you, but the moderators are interpreting this flag very strictly to prevent it from becoming an "I don't like this" button.

Comment: Not in the sense of "severe formatting problems", but I *definitely* think it has/would still have "severe content problems". I don't think we have to allow crap just to prevent low quality flags from becoming an "I don't like this" button. That seems ridiculous to me. @slhck

Comment: @CodyGray You make a good point, but the most efficient way to deal with this crap would have been to just flag it as off topic, which the community can handle just fine without needing a moderator to intervene. Closure flags are not shown to moderators anymore, which makes their queue somewhat easier manageable. Accepting a VLQ flag would have meant that the mod needed to delete the post, but in that case the OP simply should have had their post put on hold so that they could improve it later on, and possibly get it reopened.

Comment: @slhck So basically, VLQ flags get declined whenever the question can be closed for some other reason? Remind me again, then, what is their purpose? We get *free-form* closure reasons now. Any crap people throw at us can be handled effectively by the closure system.

Comment: @CodyGray At least I always decline VLQ flags when the post doesn't have to be outright deleted, and it seems that's the policy here as well. What else would you need a moderator for, if not deletion? The "usual" crap (if there's a chance for it to be improved) can be closed by the community—that's the normal process. (But if you ask me, I'd get rid of the VLQ flag entirely anyway.)

Comment: Hmm, I would delete that outright. In fact, I've already cast a vote to delete. Maybe I shouldn't admit that, in case I ever planned on running for moderator, but I don't think it serves any positive purpose leaving it on the site.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, now that it's been sitting there closed for ten days without improvement, there's definitely no point keeping it anymore. But with all the… putting on hold and "giving another chance" thing, it's unlikely the policies will change towards deleting these kinds of questions right away. At that point I can't comment anymore since Stack Overflow is too different from the other sites in that regard.

Comment: The explanations about the Low Quality flag above are correct; it's basically meant for "This post is so crappy, it needs to be deleted *now*", not simply for questions which need to be closed. That said, I don't think I disagree strongly that maybe I should have just deleted that post, and therefore marked the flag "Helpful". I've deleted the question now. /cc @CodyGray et.al.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure that I disagree with that description of the flag, I guess I just disagree about which questions are crying out for deletion. It's been a bit depressing seeing all the people who are trying to clean up the site and flagging *obviously* bad content come to Meta wondering why their flags are declined. I honestly don't have a good answer for them. I would have flagged the same stuff if I were in their shoes, and I would have deleted it if I were in ♦-shaped shoes.

Comment: Seems to me the biggest problem with this is that disagreeing with the flag automatically reduces the flag weight - even if it's a borderline case.  Is there a reason there isn't a "this flag was helpful but I don't think I will do it" option?

Comment: @Cody I think the Low Quality flag could use some clarification, or even possibly modification of its intent. I think we mods get a little bit of fatigue with them due to the large number of flags using it that don't meet the definition;I think that might make it more likely that things like this happen.

Comment: @Joe there actually is such an option. see my comment above for some related notes, too.

Comment: Oh, ok, I misread your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Thnx everyone! clarifications here does help with raising correct flags in future.